# react.js concat error value to array state

Tags: reactjs

I using react to build my page

I have array['kiwi','papaya','apple']

And I using these code

```
  if(this.state.recordFood.indexOf('kiwi') !=-1){
  this.setState({
    feedbackDisplay: [...this.state.feedbackDisplay,this.state.feedback[0].content]
  })
};
if(this.state.recordFood.indexOf('papaya') !=-1){
  this.setState({
    feedbackDisplay: [...this.state.feedbackDisplay,this.state.feedback[1].content]
  })
};
if(this.state.recordFood.indexOf('apple') !=-1){
  this.setState({
    feedbackDisplay: [...this.state.feedbackDisplay,this.state.feedback[2].content]
  })
};
```

if there is kiwi papaya apple in my array , it will concat different value to state feedbackdisplay, so after the code , I will have

this.state.feedback[0].content

this.state.feedback[1].content

this.state.feedback[2].content

in my state feedbackdisplay

but it all concat this.state.feedback[0].content to state feedback display

so I got

this.state.feedback[0].content

this.state.feedback[0].content

this.state.feedback[0].content

in my state feedbackdisplay

Answer (score 1):

`setState` does not update the state immediately, so you should pass an updater function to `setState` if you are calling it multiple times in a row. This will ensure you are using most recent state.

`this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    feedbackDisplay: [...prevState.feedbackDisplay, this.state.feedback[1].content]
}));`

Although making an array first and the calling setState once would be cleaner and easier to understand.